# Solving a non-linear equation of 3 unknowns

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following set of equation which comes from a free boundary problem. I have seen a paper which had complicated expression for the solution for even more variables. I would like to know how to solve these explicitly. The first two equations comes from a smooth fit condition, the last equation comes from continuity condition. I have tried solving it, but I have failed. but are there any standard methods?

$C_1x_*^{\beta_1}+C_2x_*^{\beta_2}=K-x_*$

$C_1\beta_1x_*^{\beta_1}+\beta_2C_2x_*^{\beta_2}=-x_*$

$C_1x_1^{\beta_1}+C_2x_1^{\beta_2}=C$

Here $x_*$, $C_1$ and $C_2$ are unkown, but $x_1$, $C$, $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are known. 
$\beta_1<0<\beta_2$. $C$ is fixed such that a solution exists for $x_1<x_*<K$

Comment: It seems that the second equation is redundant because it can be obtained by differentiating the first one with respect to $-x^*$.

Comment: @mne__povezlo no it is not, because the first equation cannot hold for every $x$. this type of thing arises from smooth fit condition for pricing of american type options in optimal stopping and my girlfriend made the identical comment, so you are not the only one thinking that!

Comment: excuse my incompetence. So is the true then that the first two equations describe the point of tangency of two curves since we'd like the values and the slopes at that point to be the same?

Comment: @mne__povezlo yes we are trying to patch up 2 equations at a point so that it is continuous at that point and their first derivative agrees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3rd equation gives $$C_2=a+bC_1$$ where $a$ and $b$ can be expressed in terms of known quantities.

Then the 1st equation becomes $$C_1x_*^{\beta_1}+(a+bC_1)x_*^{\beta_2}=K-x_*$$ which we can solve for $C_1$: $$C_1={K-x_*-ax_*^{\beta_2}\over x_*^{\beta_1}+bx_*^{\beta_2}}$$ Now we can dump all this into the 2nd equation to get something where $x_*$ is the only unknown: $${K-x_*-ax_*^{\beta_2}\over x_*^{\beta_1}+bx_*^{\beta_2}}\beta_1x_*^{\beta_1}+\beta_2\left(a+b{K-x_*-ax_*^{\beta_2}\over x_*^{\beta_1}+bx_*^{\beta_2}}\right)x_*^{\beta_2}=-x_*$$ Clearing fractions, this is $$(K-x_*-ax_*^{\beta_2})\beta_1x_*^{\beta_1}+\beta_2(a(x_*^{\beta_1}+bx_*^{\beta_2})+b(K-x_*-ax_*^{\beta_2}))x_*^{\beta_2}=-x_*(x_*^{\beta_1}+bx_*^{\beta_2})$$ Now you can multiply everything out and combine like terms. It looks like you'll get an equation involving $x_*$ to the powers $0,1+\beta_1,\beta_1+\beta_2,2\beta_2$, and $1+\beta_2$.

It will probably be hopeless to solve such an equation, other than numerically.

Comment: Thanks a lot, here is a slightly harder question, and a lot more vague, so my apologies. how would you go about proving  $x_1<x_*<K$ if I have a lower and upper bound of value of C? (I stated this as an assumption and from intuition and sketches, it is pretty clear, but there is no way of knowing)

Comment: If it helps in fact I want to show $x_1<x_*<x_0<K$ where $x_0$ is a point which satifies $K-x_0= Dx_0^{\beta_1}$ and $-x_0= D\beta_1x_0^{\beta_1}$, so $Dx^{\beta_1}$ is a touches the line $K-x$ at $x_0$. In fact, $K-x$ is its tangent at $x_0$. The condition on $C$ is that $C<(K-x_0)(x_1/x_0)^{\beta_1}$. I know that if $C=(K-x_0)(x_1/x_0)^{\beta_1}$, the solution is precisely $D\beta_1x_0^{\beta_1}$ and $x_*=x_0$. If it helps, $D=(K-x_0)(1/x_0)^{\beta_1}$

Comment: And don't worry if you do not want to help me with this. any sort of comment on theorems which might be useful is greatly appreciated.